# Parsing a string of array of arrays

Tags: kotlin

I have a string input of the following format:

```
[[10.5,125.7], [60.5, 25.6] ....]]
```

How can one parse something like this in Kotlin? This should end up as array of arrays of floats.

Comment: Assuming this is JSON, I suggest using some library for parsing JSON format. Even if this is for a very small thing. We should avoid writing our own data parsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *List<List<Float>>:*

```
val result = text
  .removeSurrounding("[[", "]]").split("], [", "],[")
  .map { it.split(",").map { s -> s.toFloat() } }
```

For an *Array<Array<Float>>:*

```
val result = text
  .removeSurrounding("[[", "]]").split("], [", "],[")
  .map { it.split(",").map { s -> s.toFloat() }.toTypedArray() }
  .toTypedArray()
```